# Want to direct wire Sirius radio to delayed shutdown of car radio

Tags: electronics

I used a fuse tap to direct wire my Sirius radio and tapped into a fuse that shuts off when I turn the car off. I didn't tap into the car radio fuse because it was still live when the car was shut off. I figured that there was continuous power to the radio to keep the clock and whatever running but I now assume that it is simply the delayed shutdown process.

So my question is would it be OK to tap into the radio fuse socket in order for  the Sirius radio to be on the same delayed shutdown?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What vehicle are you working on and Sirius system are you using?

Comment: It's a 2012 Dodge Journey SE with a Starmate 5 Sirius radio.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on what is the make model year of your car.

A normal radio has two power inputs and two power fuses. One supplies battery power and keeps the radio stations and clock from resetting. The radio also tends to draw most of the power from that fuse.

The second is a key on feed. This is like a signal that tells the radio to turn on and off. If you have this fuse, you may be able to tap into it to get the delayed accessory power.

Many vehicles such a GM has done away with the key on line. Instead they talk to the radio over the network and tell it when it should turn on and off. If you have one of these vehicles then there is little that you could do.